# Protected members in a superclass inaccessible by indirect subclass in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, package, protected

Why is it that in Java, a superclass' protected members are inaccessible by an indirect subclass in a different package? I know that a direct subclass in a different package can access the superclass' protected members. I thought any subclass can access its inherited protected members.

*EDIT*

Sorry novice mistake, subclasses can access an indirect superclasses' protected members.

Comment: It would be easier to see what you mean if you could give a concrete example.

Comment: He means that in assembly a1 there is a class a. This class has a protected member. However, he cannot access the protected member from class b that extends a in assembly a2, I think.

Comment: No, he means that he cannot access the protected member from class c in a2 that extends class b that extends class a.

Comment: What do you mean by an "indirect subclass"? Do you mean a child of a child? Or what?

Comment: Sorry I cannot post the code due to its sensitive nature. But Oscar was right it was an forgotten import declaration.

Comment: @Jay, yes a child of a child.

Comment: @MSumlong: I guess it right!!! :)  I had the same error while creating the sample code in my answer, but since it was so small I figure out immediately. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps you're a little confused.

Here's my quick demo and shows an indirect subclass accessing a protected attribute:

```
// A.java
package a;
public class A {
    protected int a;
}

// B.java 
package b;   //<-- intermediate subclass
import a.A;
public class B extends A {
}

// C.java
package c; //<-- different package 
import b.B;
public class C extends B  { // <-- C is an indirect sub class of A 
    void testIt(){
        a++;
        System.out.println( this.a );//<-- Inherited from class A
    }
    public static void main( String [] args ) {
        C c = new C();
        c.testIt();
    }
}
```

it prints 1

As you see, the attribute `a` is accessible from subclass `C`.

If you show us the code you're trying we can figure out where your confusion is.

Comment: Let me guess, you should've forgotten  a `import` declaration, as in: `import b.B`

Comment: That would be quite difficult since most compilers will complain that the extened class doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that he try to access the protected field of other instance but not his.
such like：

```
package a;
public class A{
    protected int a;
}

package b;
public class B extends A{

}

package c;
public class C extends B｛
    public void accessField(){
        A ancient = new A();
        ancient.a = 2;  //That wouldn't work.

        a = 2;   //That works.
    }


｝
```

Comment: OP seems to have figured it out.