# subclass inheritance with different packages?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, protected

Thanks for the great answers about inheritance. Just one more quick question:

A subclass can always inherit the protected members of its superclass. Is that true even if they are not in the same package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they can always inherit the protected members of its superclass **regardless** of the package they are in.

From the [`JLS Section 6.6.2`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.6.2),

> A protected member or constructor of
>   an object may be accessed from outside
>   the package in which it is declared
>   only by code that is responsible for
>   the implementation of that object.

From the [`Java Tutorial`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html),

> The protected modifier specifies that
>   the member can only be accessed within
>   its own package (as with
>   package-private) and, in addition, ***by
>   a subclass of its class in another
>   package.***

I think, this may be your  [`required solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820630/protected-members-in-a-superclass-inaccessible-by-indirect-subclass-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

Subclasses in Java have access to protected members of all superclasses, regardless of the package relationship.